# Fullpagejs makes my navigation mobile stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am working with fullpagejs and generatepress.

The page where is working fullpagejs has a navigation menu.

In mobile, when navigation menu is opened, i cant go down in the menu, the touchmove doesnt work.

If i close the menu, the touchmove works to navigate between fulpagejs

Thats my fullpagejs config

```
new fullpage("#fullpage", {
    //options here
    autoScrolling: true,
    scrollOverflow: true,
    scrollingSpeed: 700,
    css3: true,
    easingcss3:  "ease",
    anchors: [
      "project",
      "project",
      "project",
      "project",
      "project",
      "project",
      "project",
      "project",
    ],
  });

  window.addEventListener("resize", function (event) {
    fullpage_api.reBuild();
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add your menu on the `normalScrollElements` option that fullPage.js provides.

From the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> normalScrollElements: (default `null`) [Demo](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/RmVazM) If you want to avoid the auto scroll when scrolling over some elements, this is the option you need to use. (useful for maps, scrolling divs etc.) It requires a string with the Javascript selectors for those elements. (For example: `normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2'`). This option should not be applied to any section/slide element itself.